# Is there a common embedded console library

Tags: embedded, standard, library

Does anyone know or of use a standard set of source files for a simple embedded console?

I've been doing embedded work for a few years now, and I have a set of console code files I have reused in several situations.  I've searched the web before for common console code, and I have not found a standard library.

I have tried using different RTOS solutions, and I have written my own console's that work A-OK. I'm just hoping to find a standard reference implementation to recommend to others, or to work on and with to improve quality and number of developers on a project.

Answer (score 1):

Atmel have an appnote and some software to implement a simple ANSI console. (AVR244)

Check [this](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?module=Freaks%20Tools&func=viewItem&item_id=501) out.

Answer (score 1):

I've always just written a custom console for my applications. I do reuse code between them a lot though depending on what type of support they need to provide.

I base most of my consoles on a command/response format where the system provides a prompt '>' then the user enters a command which is buffered. When the user enters a 'CR' the buffered command is executed. The system generates a reply and provides another prompt.

If the interface to the console is automated and binary transfers are required you will need to come up with a way to escape the 'CR' so that it is not interpreted as an end of command.

As far as I can tell the basic components of any console are:

- Interrupt for receiving and buffering input
- Task for processing buffered input and printing the response